# Is there a way of seeing what `brew cask zap` does before it does it?

Tags: homebrew

I'd like to see the results of

```
brew cask zap <something>
```

so I can decide whether I want it to do that before it does it.  Is there anything equivalent to a `--dry-run` option, that I'm somehow missing?  Or any other way of achieving the same results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way of doing a dry run of a `brew cask zap` command.

You could look at the recipe and work out from that what the command will do. According to the `man` page the command will...

> Implicitly performs all actions associated with uninstall, even if the Cask does not appear to be currently installed.
>
> Removes all staged versions of the Cask distribution found under /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/
>
> If  the  Cask definition contains a zap stanza, performs additional zap actions as defined there, such as removing local preference files. zap actions are variable, depending on the level of detail defined by the Cask author.
>
> zap may remove resources which are shared between applications.

So running `brew cask cat <something>` and examining the uninstall stanza (and the zap stanza if it is present) should give you a general idea of the files that `zap` will remove.

Longer term you could [request](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/new) a "dry run" feature.