# How do you edit Homebrew's `zap` stanza?

Tags: homebrew

I found [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221313/is-there-a-way-of-seeing-what-brew-cask-zap-does-before-it-does-it#221346) describing how to see what `zap` will remove.  I recently downloaded a game launcher using `brew cask`, but in the process of installing the game, it installed a bunch of other stuff that I would like to be deleted if I `zap` the cask.  How can I add to the `zap trash` or `zap rmdir` section of the stanza so that these other files are removed if I decide to `zap` the application?